# Sample mean and variance of a Weibull distribution sample

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, probability-theory, weibull

Let's suppose that I have a random sample x from a Weibull distribution with shape parameter k=1 and scale parameter λ=2.
How am I supposed to compute the mean value of the sample? Also what can I do to compute the variance of the sample?

I would also  appreciate any helpful Matlab code able to perform the aforementioned tasks.

Comment: Use `mean(sample(:))` and  `var(sample(:))`. You can remove `(:)` if `sample` is already a vector (1D-array)

Comment: but aren't the mean and var commands supposed to be computing the mean and variance of a normal distribution only ??

Comment: No! They are quite general

Comment: Well, the mean of a weibull is well-defined if you have the shape and scale parameters, so you could use that (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) and compare it to the mean you get from your sample.

Comment: ok then suppose i have generated a first sample with the afformentioned values... in case I divide all the values of the sample by 5, what should change in the recalculated mean and variance ??

Comment: In that case, of course, the mean will be divided by 5 and the variance by 25... but why do you ask that?

Comment: No, in my opinion the question does not need rethinking... since I just added an objective to the original one...

Comment: By the way is there any formal reason the variance is divided by 25 ??

Comment: @obelix It follows directly from the [definition of variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random numbers for Weibul distribution with scale parameter λ and  shape parameter k:

```
Numbers = wblrnd(λ,k);
```

To compute the mean

```
mean(Numbers(:));
```

To compute the variance

```
var(Numbers(:));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
mean(sample(:))
```

and

```
var(sample(:))
```

where `sample` is an array of numbers.

The `(:)` part is used to turn the array `sample` into a vector. You can omit that if `sample` is already a vector.

Note that this computes the [*sample mean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_sample_covariance) and [*sample variance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) of your data (not the true mean and variance of the distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the wiki page for the [Weibull Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), these can be directly computed for the distribution.  See wiki for formulas.

```
k = 1;          % shape parameter
lambda = 2;     % scale parameter

Wmeanh =@(k,lambda) lambda*gamma(1 + (1/k));    % Mean
Wvarh =@(k,lambda) (lambda^2)*(gamma(1+(2/k)) - (gamma(1+(1/k)))^2); % Variance
```

Now to test these anonymous function handles out on our parameters...

```
>> Wmeanh(k,lambda)
ans =
     2
>> Wvarh(k,lambda)
ans =
     4
```

And we can verify our formulas are correct and show that our answers agree.

```
% Test against alternate method
pd = makedist('Weibull',lambda,k)
mean(pd)
var(pd)
```

Below we generate samples from this distribution with different sample sizes and collect the sample mean and sample variance. This demonstrates how to get this from a sample and that our previous calculations appear correct.

```
N = [10 30 90 270 810 2430 7290]';
SampleMEAN = zeros(size(N));
SampleVAR = zeros(size(N));
for i = 1:length(N)
    ni = N(i);
    Xi = random(pd,ni,1);
    SampleMEAN(i) = mean(Xi);
    SampleVAR(i) = var(Xi);
end
T = table(N,SampleMEAN,SampleVAR)
```